# Coldfusion "can't find object" error but can find in other part of code

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

In the code below, the query where I truncate the table throws the error:

> "Error Executing Database Query.[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Cannot find the object ""temp_person"" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

But if I comment it out, the same datasource/table combination does not throw an error when I insert into the table. If I manually truncate the table in SSMS, and then run the process, the data copies fine. But if I run it again, I obviously get dups.

Why can't CF find the table when I try to truncate it, but can when I insert?

**Code:**

```
<cffunction name="copyProdToDev">

    <cfargument name="devDatasource" >
    <cfargument name="prodDataSource" type="string">
    <cfargument name="devTableName" type="string">
    <cfargument name="prodTableName" type="string">
    <cfargument name="dateColumnName" default="none">
    <cfargument name="startDate" default=Now()>

    <h1>In function</h1>

    <cfquery name="ProdData" datasource="#prodDatasource#" timeout="60">
        SELECT *
        FROM #prodTableName#
        <cfif dateColumn neq "none">
        WHERE #dateColumn# > <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#startDate#">
        </cfif>
    </cfquery>

    <cfset columnNames = ProdData.getColumnNames()> 
    <cfset numColumns = ArrayLen(columnNames)>

    <cfdump var="#columnNames#">


    <cfdump var="#devTableName#" abort="false">
    <cfquery datasource="#devDatasource#" timeout="60">
        TRUNCATE TABLE #devTableName#
    </cfquery>

    <cfloop query="#ProdData#">

        <cfquery datasource="#devDatasource#" timeout="60">
            INSERT INTO #devTableName# VALUES
            (
            <cfloop index="colNumber" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(columnNames)-1#">
                <cfset columnData = "#ProdData[columnNames[colNumber]][currentrow]#">
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#columnData#">,
            </cfloop>
            <cfset columnData = "#ProdData[columnNames[numColumns]][currentrow]#">
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#columnData#">
            )
        </cfquery>

        (
        <cfloop index="colNumber" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(columnNames)-1#">
            <cfset columnData = "#ProdData[columnNames[colNumber]][currentrow]#">
            <cfoutput>#columnData#, &nbsp;</cfoutput>
        </cfloop>
        <cfset columnData = "#ProdData[columnNames[numColumns]][currentrow]#">
        <cfoutput>#columnData#</cfoutput>
        )<br />
    </cfloop>

</cffunction>
```

Comment: Is it a #temp or permanent table? Just to confirm, are you using the same DSN for both cfquery's?

Comment: Permanent. same DSN--`devDataSource`. Actually, I created a table called `temp_person` on the dev server for testing the process. Ultimately the data is going to go from prod.person to dev.person. And also all the other tables I need to copy...

Comment: Then it could be a permissions problem. Are you using the same account for SSMS and the CF DSN? If not, does the DSN account have permissions to TRUNCATE that table and do the CF DSN settings allow TRUNCATE?

Comment: Now there's a good question. The physical machine being used for the server was recently changed (data migrated to a new server). Perhaps I have insert permissions, but not truncate permissions? I'll ask the sysadmin to look into it.

Comment: Yup. I was logged into SSMS as admin and the CF datasource was logged in as user.

Comment: So it was a "permissions" problem (or lack there of in this case ;-) ?

Comment: Yes. I was logging into SSMS with higher permissions than the CF datasource has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From the comments)

If it is a permanent table, and works from SSMS, then it could be a permissions problem. Are you using the same account under SSMS and for the CF Datasource? If not, verify whether the CF Datasource account has permissions to `TRUNCATE` that table. Also check the CF Datasource settings for any restrictions. See the "Allowed SQL operations" section.

Based on the error message, it sounds like either the account or DSN settings do not have `TRUNCATE` permissions for that object.